# fill sheet with values if they occure in another sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

i have 2 sheets:

Sheet 1:
[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL2w3.png)

Sheet 2:
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWqlI.png)

I want to create a formular that is able to select only the relevant information from sheet 1 as soon as a new entry (Starting with "New Meter ID) is done and append these new relevant information to sheet 2. Sheet 2 Shows how it should look like.

Here is my pseudocode logic:

```
IF there is a new Value in "New Meter ID":
   Select "Old Meter ID", "Building ID", "Address", "active", "p_Name", "POD ID" and put it 
   into sheet 2.
```

Anybody has an idea?

**UPDTAE**

Here is current sheet. My Problem with the filter function is, that the filtered data doesn't start at the beginning of the sheet. In a sheet with 1000 + rows, this will lead to many empty rows between the filtered data.

See Picture 3
[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apd4d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:I; Sheet1!B2:B<>"")
```

### update:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!B2:C, Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!G2:I}, Sheet1!B2:B<>"")
```

or:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!B2:C\ Sheet1!E2:E\ Sheet1!G2:I}; Sheet1!B2:B<>"")
```

Comment: This gives me the complete row. Is there a way to select just the relevant columns?

Comment: @HectorDevough sure, answer updated

Comment: What does the B<>"" mean exactly ?

Comment: @HectorDevough it exactly means: "B is not empty"

Comment: Ok cool this works 80%. But now i have the problem, that where the filter is finding nothing, it just leaves the row blank. Is there a way to not create blank rows, so that all entrys are under each other like in Sheet 2?

Comment: @HectorDevough can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: @HectorDevough wrap it into QUERY and filter out empty rows: `=QUERY(fx_here, "where Col1 is not null", )`